# how to fix codeigniter non-object error in PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

we're using codeigniter with postgresql, our following code works in MySQL type database, but in postgresql, it shows errror

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /application/models/category_m.php on line 61
```

**Our Model Code:**

```
$this->db->select('ci_categories.cat_id, ci_categories.cat_name, COUNT(ci_albums.album_id) AS total_albums');
$this->db->from('ci_categories');
$this->db->join('ci_albums', 'ci_albums.cat_id = ci_categories.cat_id', 'left');

return $this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set dbdriver in    application/config/database.php

```
  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "postgres";
```

The error is likely due to the fact that the query (and resulting **result()** object) are empty. Ensure that the query actually returns at least one record before attempting to use the **result()** object:

```
   $this->db->select('ci_categories.cat_id, ci_categories.cat_name, COUNT(ci_albums.album_id) AS total_albums');
   $this->db->from('ci_categories');
   $this->db->join('ci_albums', 'ci_albums.cat_id = ci_categories.cat_id', 'left');

   $query=$this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: hello, thanks for answering, but its already set to 'postgre', and all other controller work fine for me, maybe it some kind of issue with query ...

Comment: @user1218948,The result of query was empty?Could you check my updated answer

Comment: it returns Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in

Answer (score 0):

try this on the last line --

```
$query  = $this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get();
 return ($query)?$query->result():array(); // instead of false you can return empty array if you need
```

Comment: it return Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(); it mean, we get FALSE from model...

Comment: the return array() instead of false  **return ($query)?$query->result():array();**

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
$this->db->select('ci_categories.cat_id, ci_categories.cat_name, COUNT(ci_albums.album_id) AS total_albums',FALSE);
$this->db->from('ci_categories');
$this->db->join('ci_albums', 'ci_albums.cat_id = ci_categories.cat_id', 'left');

return $this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get()->result();
```

Comment: it return Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in, in MYSQL it work fine, but in PostGreSQL it return same...

Comment: try to print last query ... using this  `$this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get();` and after this line `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: SELECT "ci_categories"."cat_id", "ci_categories"."cat_name", COUNT(ci_albums.album_id) AS total_albums FROM "ci_categories" LEFT JOIN "ci_albums" ON "ci_albums"."cat_id" = "ci_categories"."cat_id" GROUP BY "ci_categories"."cat_id"

Comment: try using `return $this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get()->result_array();`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in

Comment: just try doing this ... `$qry = $this->db->group_by('ci_categories.cat_id')->get()` and then print this variable using `echo "<pre>";print_r($qry);exit;`

Comment: print_r return nothing, i tried, var_dump, it returns bool(false)

Comment: when i removed join and group_by, query proceed, you can allow me simple query for postgres? maybe alternative query work?